# AngularFirebase how make the query.once operation wait till it returns the value?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular5

I am using Angular and Firebase for my webapp. 
I am calling a function of a service (A-service.ts) from the constructor of a component class(A-component.ts) to get a user name.

**Constructor code:**

```
constructor(private aService: AService, private firebase: AngularFireDatabase) { 
    this.userName = aService.getUserName(firebase)[0];   }
```

**Service code:**

```
var user = [];
    var query = firebase.database.ref("Users").orderByKey();
    query.once("value")
      .then(function (snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
          var key = childSnapshot.key;
          var childData = childSnapshot.val();
          if (key = localStorage.getItem("LoggedUser")) {
            user.push(childData.Name);
          }
        });
      });
    return user;
  }
```

So the issue with the code is that inside the service method, the `query.once`  is behaving asynchronously and thus I am not able to return the user correctly to the constructor.

Could any one please suggest a solution to the same.?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good `rxjs` package that can do this for you. Take a look at `rxjs/toPromise`.

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/topromise.md

If you import it to your `service`, or `app.module.ts` file.

`import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';`

You're then receiving a promise, instead of an observable, but you still need to handle this logic in the constructor.

`constructor`

```
constructor(private aService: AService, private firebase: AngularFireDatabase) { 
  aService.getUserName(firebase)
    .then(user => {
      this.userName = user;
    });
}
```

`service`

```
return firebase.database().ref('Users')
  .orderByKey()
  .once('value')
  .toPromise()
  .then(snapshot => {
    const user = [];
    snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
      const key = childSnapshot.key;
      const childData = childSnapshot.val();

      if (key = localStorage.getItem('LoggedUser')) {
        user.push(childData.Name);
      }
    });

    if (user.length > 0) {
      return user[0];
    }
  });
```

Comment: Hi Thank you, I understood the solution. 
since I am using AngularFireDatabase.database() it gives an error like "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'Database' has no compatible call signatures." They only allow AngularFireDatabase.database(and not AngularFireDatabase.database()). If we use the database, toPromise is not a funtion of database.

Answer (score 1):

If you want username to change live with the changes in database values, you could return as an observable itself display in html.
For more reference, checkout [Top 7 RxJS Concepts for Angular Developers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65Us8NwmYf4).

component.html

```
<div>{{username | async}}</div>
```

component.ts

```
username;
constructor(private aService: AuthService) {
    this.username = aService.getUserName();
}
```

AuthService.ts

```
getUserName() {
    return firebase.database().ref('Users').val();
}
```

Edit:
If you want username value in component.ts, then replace constructor with

```
username;
subscription;
constructor(private aService: AuthService) {
    this.subscription = aService.getUserName().subscribe((user) => {
        this.username = username;
    });
}
ngOnDestroy(){
    this.subscription.unsubcribe();
}
```

Comment: Hi,
Thank you. I need the to get the user in the component.ts not in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it. I change the return type of the method to Promise and return the promise to the constructor to get the value.

Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968911/sketchthat for providing me a way to approach it.